# IllegalStateException when exiting app

Tags: java, android

I have `Runnable` that runs in `Thread` in a `MediaPlayer` `Service`. When I exit the app after I stop the service I get an IllegalStateException.

here's the `Runnable`

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (isActive) {
                while (progressStatus < 1000) {
                    progressStatus += 1;
                    // Update the progress bar and display the
                    //current value in the text view
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if (result != null) {
                                result.putInt(UIFragment.MAX_KEY, mPlayer.getDuration());
                                result.putInt(UIFragment.PROGRESS_KEY, mPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                                progressReciever.send(UIFragment.RESULT_DATA_RETURNED, result);
                            } else {
                                Log.d("Player", "is null");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.
                        //Just to display the progress slowly
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    };
```

Here's how it's called in the `onPrepared`

```
            handler=new Handler();
            thread= new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
```

and in my `onDestroy` I call

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
thread.interrupt();
```

**EDIT**
StackTrace

```
02-13 00:04:19.722  13929-13929/com.brianstacks.servicefundamentals E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.brianstacks.servicefundamentals, PID: 13929
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.getDuration(Native Method)
            at com.brianstacks.servicefundamentals.services.MusicPlayerService$1$1.run(MusicPlayerService.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Can you post a stack trace?  Also, unless you're doing something more than what I'm seeing if you're not using hanlder.post(Runnable) or postDelayed(Runnable, long), then removing the callbacks doesn't really serve a purpose.

Comment: the `Handler` post in the `Runnable` method

Comment: Are you checking to make sure the media play's preparation callbacks have been hit before accessing the duration?

Comment: I thought I was with the `Boolean` `isActive` in the `Runnable` method I set it false in `onCompletion` and true in `onPrepared`

Comment: Since you're using two separate threads you need to gaurd against that in a different way.  If your thread has already checked "isAlive" and is executing your  "progressStatus" while loop, the second while loop will still run if that boolean changes after the initial check.  This will cause the the handler to still post requests to your mediaplayer after it shouldn't.  You need to either gaurd against this usecase using a wrapper class around the media player, or placing the second while loop in an interrupt try block and interupting the thread when tearing down your media player.

Comment: Ok thanks going to try to implement this now and I will report back

Comment: Also probably safer to interrupt first, then remove callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by removing the new `Thread` all together and just letting the `Handler` control the `Runnable` Here's the code:

```
private Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            if (result != null) {
                result.putInt(UIFragment.MAX_KEY, mPlayer.getDuration());
                result.putInt(UIFragment.PROGRESS_KEY, mPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                progressReciever.send(UIFragment.RESULT_DATA_RETURNED, result);

            } else {
                Log.d("Player", "is null");
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
```

in onPrepared

```
handler=new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

in onDestroy

```
handler.removeCallbacks(r);
```

now app exits with no errors thanks to @Submersed for making me think through the logic a bit more.